# Best coding practice for Xcode variable types?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, coding-style

I was just looking through my code and wondering about the standards of obj.c in xcode. We have all these NS(insert object type) which overlap with the original C, C++ objects. I wanted to clarify between different alternatives of snippets of code. Even better than explaining each one would be a link to a guide or reference containing all these.

`object.property = blah;` or `[object setProperty:blah];`
`float aFloat = 0.01;`(or `double`) or `CGFloat aFloat = 0.01`
`int anInt = 1` or `NSInteger anInt = 1`
`@"%d", anInt` or `@"%i", anInt`

Thanks

Comment: Xcode has no variable types — it is an IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one (dot notation vs method calls) is purely a thing of taste. `man printf` says that `%d` and `%i` both are placeholders for signed decimal, hence ObjC being strict superset of C doesn't change their meaning.

Types with `NS` or `CG` prefixes are platform dependent and are actually `typedef`'ed from standard C types. If you decide to compile for different platforms (say 32/64 bit) using NS/CG types will fall back to default types of the platform you're compiling for. Take for example `NSInteger` (snippet from NSObjCRuntime.h):

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

It shows that if you're not compiling for iOS, the NSInteger will stand for `long`, otherwise - it will be simple `int`.

**Personal opinion**

I always use `%d` since I saw it first in some ObjC tutoria. Never looked back on other placeholders for integers (unless `%lld`). I use the dot notation only if receiver type is known at compile time. Sometimes you may have to write this:

```
id possiblyView = [someObject someView];
// the following line will give compile warning
possiblyView.frame
// the following line won't
[possiblyView frame];
```

The result of those calls is the same, but the first line forces compiler look for `frame` variable under id-typed structure.

And I always try to use the NS/CG variable types since they make code look more ObjC-ish than C-ish.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I'll probably start using the NS/CG variable types consistently so my code looks "ObjC-ish" :D.